# How can I test my trained network on the next unavailable hour?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, prediction, matlab, time-series

I have data of 695 hours. I use the first 694 hours to train the network and I use 695th hour to validate it. Now my goal is to predict the next hour.

How I can use my trained network to predict the next hour, that is, the 696th hour (which I do not have access to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have access to the 696th hour (or successive hours), otherwise, you cannot test your model. An alternative would be, for example, to train your model on the first 693 hours, validate it on the 694th hour, and test it on the 695th hour.